# Finding $A$ and $b$ if we know $x$ for $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question that appeared on a previous quiz.  Nobody I know, including myself, has been able to figure it out.

If $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ equal to $$\left[ 4-6s_1+5s_2,s_1,-9+s_2,s_2 \right]$$ then find a matrix $A$ with 4 columns and a vector $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where the above x is a solution for $Ax=b$

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to pick $A = I$. Can you see what $b$ should be in this example?

Comment: I think that $s_1$ and $s_2$ are meant to represent parameters, and that Jason means "vectors of the form given constitute the general solution to the equation $Ax=b$."

Comment: We haven't learned identity matrix's yet.  Additionally, isn't our $x$ vector of dimension 4? But our output is of dimension 2, and we need to have 4 columns in our matrix.  Isn't this impossible?

Comment: Jason, if the variables are $x$, $y$, $z$, $w$, in that order, which variables are free variables in your solution set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is a little vague; but it's an interesting question.

If you mean that for any given $s_1,s_2$ you want to then find $A$ and $b$ satisfying $Ax=b$, then just let $A$ be the identity matrix, and let $b=x$. Of course, the $A,b$ that works for one pair $s_1,s_2$ wouldn't necessarily work for the pair $s'_1, s'_2$.

Or perhaps you want a different constraint: let $A$ be the 4x4 zero matrix with $A_{ij} = 0$; and $b$ be the zero vector in $\mathbb R^4$. Then we can say that for all $s_1,s_2 \in \mathbb R$, we will have $Ax = b$. Of course, that would be true whatever our definition of $x = x(s_1, s_2)$; so again not so insightful!

Finally, we could ask: are there $A, b$ s.t. $Ax = b$ if, and only if, $x = \left[ 4-6s_1+5s_2,s_1,-9+s_2,s_2 \right]$ for some $s_1, s_2 \in \mathbb R$?